# Alternative to BitmapImage operations on the UI thread?

Tags: c#, .net, user-interface, winrt-xaml, win-universal-app

I would like to create a worker class that can retrieve laggy resources (eg from a database or over a network), and prepare them for later, zero-lag display on the UI. That worker class should not be bound to the UI or to the UI thread i.e. it should be able to run anywhere.  When done, it's output will be a populated array of some image container class that the UI can work with easily.

My first thought was to use the BitmapImage class as the image container; however that inherits from the DependencyObject class, which will restrict access from any non-UI thread. As @Filip pointed out in my earlier form of this question, this is not inherently a problem, but it would restrict the generality of my worker class.

Is there a better Windows class that I can use as the basis for the image container, and then convert to BitmapImage on the UI thread at bind time?
Or a better way altogether?
Here is some pseudo code to indicate what I'm trying to do, using an array of URIs for the source images.

In the worker class

```
ImageContainerClass[] prepImages(Uri[] uriSet)
{
    ImageContainerClass[] iccSet = new ImageContainerClass[uriSet.Length];
    for (int i = 0; i < iccSet.Length; i++)
        iccSet[i] = new ImageContainerClass.retrieveImage(uriSet[i]); 
    return iccSet;
}
```

On the UI thread (at some later time):

```
BitmapImage bmi = new BitmapImage();
var image = iccSet[i].getImage();
<<some operation to set the source of bmi to the image>>
someImage.Source = bmi;
```

Comment: You can easily create BitmapImage instances (or instances of any other class derived from BitmapSource) on a non-UI thread and then use them in the UI thread. You just have to make sure to call their `Freeze()` method to make them cross-thread accessible.

Comment: Hi Clemens - thanks for this.  I'm not sure that I understand fully.  Cpl of questions:  (*) I'm using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage; there doesn't seem to be a Freeze method?; I see other evidence that it does exist; am I maybe in a new / different class hierarchy?  (*) The act of creating the instance will bomb with a thread error; do I need to create on the UI thread, Freeze (somehow), and then pass to the background thread?

Comment: I removed `wpf` from your question tags and added `win-universal-app`. Please note that these are different frameworks.

Comment: The correct place to do UI logic is on the UI thread. If you're doing something in a sub-thread, then use a delegate to access the UI thread, or better still post state back to the UI thread and let it handle it in a thread safe manner e.g. via a Timer to update the UI accordingly based on the messages that have been posted to it in its queue.

Comment: Thanks Clemens; I didn't add the wpf tag; some other editor did. I'm sure your edit is correct.  Thanks ManoDestra; I know that the correct place to do UI logic is on that thread.  My point is that I'm not doing UI logic - I'm preparing an array of objects that will later be bound to a UI element. I'm happy to believe that I'm using the wrong class, and should not be using BitmapImage at all.

Comment: I added some code to make the goal clearer, in response to Clemens' and ManoDestra's feedback.

Comment: @jbhelicon - When responding to someone on SO you should use the `@` notation in front of their user ID to get their attention. Sometimes it is automatic, but most of the time you need to explicitly do it.

Comment: Thanks @Enigmativity - shall do, and appreciated.

Comment: @jbhelicon - There you go. Awesome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, so here's a solution that appears to work.

The following code will run happily on a non-UI thread:

```
    internal async Task<InMemoryRandomAccessStream> getImage(Uri uri)
    {
        try {
            var httpClient = new HttpClient();
            IBuffer iBuffer = await httpClient.GetBufferAsync(uri);
            byte[] bytes = iBuffer.ToArray();
            InMemoryRandomAccessStream ims = new InMemoryRandomAccessStream();
            DataWriter dataWriter = new DataWriter(ims);
            dataWriter.WriteBytes(bytes);
            await dataWriter.StoreAsync();
            ims.Seek(0);
            return ims;
        } catch (Exception e) { return null; }
    }
```

Then, the following code may be executed on the UI thread when the image needs to be displayed:

```
BitmapImage bmi = new BitmapImage();
bmi.SetSource(ims);
someImage.Source = bmi;
```

I'm sure this can be cleaned up by people more familiar with the relevant frameworks, but hopefully this will help others.  My thanks to @Filip for putting me on the right track.

Answer (score 1):

I think loading images into `BitmapImage` happens on a background thread in the platform, so there shouldn't be a need for you to do it. You could probably use `BitmapDecoder` on a background thread if you needed to and then maybe push a pixel buffer into a `WriteableBitmap`, but you wouldn't gain much from it. If you really want to force all the code to a background thread then you can use DirectX interop and have a completely separate background render thread for your stuff.

Comment: Hi Filip.  Thanks for this.  I've added some code to my question which maybe helps explain what I'm trying to do.

Comment: Hi Filip.  Sorry to be dumb; I don't know what "Yeah, no" means?  And when you say "that code" which code do you mean?  I assume you mean your code? [My code doesn't run at all]

Comment: Sorry, what I meant to say was that you should create your `BitmapImage` objects on the UI thread and not worry too much about threading here since they can't be created on a background thread anyway and the platform streams and decodes them off the UI thread by itself.

If you already do other stuff on the background thread - you should invoke the creation of the `BitmapImages` through the dispatcher.

Comment: Thanks @Filip; that's helpful.  I suspect I'm laboring under a misapprehension.  I'd understood that when I do an operation such as `new BitmapImage(uri)` then a network-bound operation will be kicked off, as the uri is resolved and retrieved, and that therefore I don't want to do that on the UI thread or the UI will stutter.  That's incorrect?

Comment: It's hard to answer to a question "it's incorrect", but it is incorrect. Setting a property is non blocking. A BitmapImage has an event that's raised when it loads. Setting the uri starts a background operation, so no, you don't need to offload it to a background thread yourself.

Comment: Hi @Filip.  Got it.  The funny thing is that I'm not deliberately offloading it to a background thread; I'm implementing an MVP model where everything possible is declared async.  It's the Model that's doing the collection, and it ends up (properly, I would have thought) on a different thread to the View.  Now, somewhat weirdly, I need to force this Model function back onto the View thread.  A better solution I think is the one that you initially proposed - use some other class (maybe `BitmapDecoder`) to retrieve the resources, and then figure how to hand that off to the View class?

Comment: You could collect Uris in the view model and then pass them on to the view through a dispatcher invocation.

Comment: I edited my question, hopefully in a way that makes it more useful to the community, while still utilizing your feedback here.